# Is the mapping from a Schatten-class compact operator to its spectrum continuous?

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces, spectral-theory, compact-operators

On an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, let $S_p$ be the Banach space of compact operators that are $p$ Schatten class. Since for $A\in S_p$ its spectrum $\sigma(A)$ is at most countably infinite, we can naturally consider it as an element of the Banach space $\ell_p$

Is the mapping from an operator to its spectrum $\sigma: S_p \to \ell_p$ continuous for any $p\in [1,\infty]$? This is true for finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces but I'm wondering how it generalizes.

In particular, what if we restrict things to the subspace of $S_p$ consisting of self-adjoint operators?

Comment: So, what is the map $\sigma:S_p\rightarrow \ell_p$? Can you be more specific (even in the finite-dimensional case)? Is it basis dependent?

Comment: $\sigma$ maps an operator to its spectrum and is basis-independent. I rewrote the question to be more explicit.

Comment: Suppose $1, 2, i+1$ are the eigenvalues of some operator $A$. So, do you map it to $(1, 2, i+1)$ or $(2, 1, i+1)$ or $(i+1, 2, 1)$...? All I wanted to say is that $\ell_p$ has ordering but the spectrum does have a natural order. Maybe the easiest might be to consider the ordering by the magnitude of the eigenvalues. Of course, in the end it doesn't really matter when it comes to the continuity since all of these ordering are unitarily equivalent.

Comment: Ah I see what you meant now. For concreteness, we'll order for the eigenvalues by decreasing absolute value.

Comment: Then what is the difficulty? Is it obvious then?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The only thing I can think is that since finite rank operators are dense in $S_p$, $\sigma$ being uniformly continuous for finite dimensions would give us the desired result. But that fact isn't obvious to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is less of an answer and more of a related result that came to mind: Lemma 5 in Chapter XI.9 of the Dunford & Schwartz classic ["Linear operators. Part II. Spectral theory"](https://books.google.de/books/about/Linear_Operators_Spectral_theory.html?id=kuVQAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) reads

> Let $T_n,T$ be compact operators, and let $T_n\to T$ in the uniform operator topology. Let $\lambda_m(T)$ be an enumeration of the non-zero eigenvalues of $T$, each repeated according to its multiplicity. Then there exist enumerations $\lambda_m(T_n)$ of the non-zero eigenvalues of $T_n$, with repetitions according to multiplicity, such that
> $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda_m(T_n)=\lambda_m(T),\qquad m\geq 1,
> $$
> the limit being uniform in $m$.

Once the spectral mapping $\sigma:\mathcal K(\mathcal H)\to\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ (resp. the restriction to some Schatten class) is well-defined${}^1$ this result may allow to generalize the result from finite dimensions to the general setting.

---

<sub>${}^1$: In a comment you specified that $\sigma$ shall order the eigenvalues of the input decreasingly according to its absolute value, but this leaves room for problems. For example if the input has eigenvalues $i$, $-i$ then $\sigma$ fails to give a unique ordering to them. Of course this problem vanishes for the simpler special case of self-adjoint operators you mentioned in your post; so you may want to try to rigorously formulate and prove that result first and then try to "make sense" of the case of arbitrary input operators.</sub>